# Why is secureserver.net (GoDaddy) showing up blacklisted from my domain blacklist checker thingy?

Tags: network, dns-domain

I have my business website through GoDaddy and there has been some weird stuff happening within my business over the past year costing me a lot of money and all of my free time trying to figure out what is actually going on. I have even tried hiring 4 different IT professionals and they swear it's fixed but it's not. I set up a Blacklist checker thingy for my domain and stuff.

Today I get a report stating:

```
.....m1pismtp01-v01.prod.mesa1.secureserver.net Blacklisted.....
```

why is this?

Comment: I love "Blacklist checker thingy"

Comment: You will have to tell us what that "blacklist checker thingy" is and what it is actually preventing you to do for us to be able to give you any meaningful answer without resorting to speculation. As it currently stands, your question is vague and unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Also, be careful of posting network names as it's easily reversed into an IP address. So I've done that and checked the associated IP for reasons for being blacklisted through the use of [public DNSBLs](http://www.ipvoid.com/scan/216.69.186.201/) and didn't find any reason for it. It might be blacklisted in private blacklists though for running on a web hosting company's IP range (something I do as well, as there's no legitimate reasons for those servers accessing mine). But as I said those reasons are private and nothing we can answer here. Query the service provider blacklisting your IP.

Answer (score 2):

If you took a moment to Google your server (m1pismtp01-v01.prod.mesa1.secureserver.net) you would see that you are not the only user of this server. In fact, the likelihood is, there are hundreds, maybe even thousands, using this same server. When this occurs, you are feeling the aftermath of what someone else did prior to you. (Spam, malware, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Run, run run run from godaddy...

If you are running (no pun intended) a business, I recommend you get a new host and pay a little bit more but get better service.  I have helped people in the past get off godaddy services as they oversell and consistently get blacklisted (email / web).

Get a VM from folks like http://linode.com and hire an it pro to manage it for you (if needed).  At least that way you will be better off and not lose money.

Your Godaddy hosting cannot be fixed, it is oversold and abused.

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment of your answer, mostly because I agree with it, but that's personal opinions of us two and it doesn't really answer the question. Granted, even the question itself is rather vague and might not be possible to answer in its current form. :}

Comment: @TildalWave I suspect since `smtp` is listed, he is having email problems (which almost all users run into with godaddy businesses).  There is really no way to fix a service that is abused so much that it is blacklisted on a weekly basis.